# Create new array from integer elements of another array? MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, integer, find, isinteger

I have created an array `tP` which contains a mix of integer and non-integer elements. I want to create a new array of the integer element.

The result I would like is in the same form as is returned for, for example:

```
tP2=find(tP>300);
```

That is, a list of the element numbers which contain integer values, not a list of the integers themselves.

From this I will then select the desired elements like so:

```
tP3=tP(tP2);
```

To do this for integers, what I currently have is:

```
tP2=find(isinteger(int16(tP)));
```

But instead of a list of element numbers, I just get `tP2=1` returned.

Why does `isinteger` not work in this case and how can I achieve my required result? Thanks.

Comment: Besides your question, take a look at logical indexing. You can also use `tP3=tP(tP>300)`

Comment: I don't understand your question, an array (aka matrix) is either double or uint8 or any other type, but all elements have the same type. What data type is `tP2`? How is it created?

Comment: `isinterger` refers to data type. A `double` for example can have an integer value and it will still be a `double`, not an integer data type

Comment: @Daniel: Well, a cell array can have elements with different data types.  So in that case `isinteger` might return multiple values (I didn't bother to check if it can be used on cell arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `round`

```
tp2 = find( tP == round(tP) );
```

Answer (score 0):

As Shai says, comparison to `round` is an effective way to detect integers.

Next, unless you need the list of matches for something else, you don't need `find`.  Just the comparison will create a mask array, and masks can be used for subscripting.

```
tP3 = tP(tP == round(tP));
```

Getting rid of `tP2` and the call to `find` should save time and memory.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I should have specified that I am using that list of element numbers for other arrays as well so will keep tP2, but I shall keep the tip in mind for the future.